# How to unpack dictionary if values are lists?

Tags: python

**Problem**

I want to unpack some OrderedDict that has lists as values.

```py
from collections import OrderedDict
d = OrderedDict()
d["mark"] = [0,'a']
d["bob"] = [1,'b']
d["mark"] = [0,'c']
d["can"] = [2,'d']

with open("data.txt", 'w+') as data_file:
    for key,value in d:
        if key.startswith("mark"):
            data_file.write("\n")
            data_file.write(str(value[1]) + "\n")
        else:
            data_file.write(key + "=" + str(value[0]) + str(value[1]) + "\n")
    data_file.write("\n")
```

**Error**

ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Comment: Hi, please always make it a point to share the full traceback for the error. It makes debugging a lot easier to help with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with `for k, v in d:` you are not passing the individual elements of `d` to `k`, and `v`, you are passing `d` itself and trying to assign it to two variables. You need `d.items()`, which provides an iterable of the elements inside `d`:

```py
from collections import OrderedDict
d = OrderedDict()
d["mark"] = [0,'a']
d["bob"] = [1,'b']
d["mark"] = [0,'c']
d["can"] = [2,'d']

with open("data.txt", 'w+') as data_file:
    for key, value in d.items():    # change here
        if key.startswith("mark"):
            data_file.write("\n")
            data_file.write(str(value[1]) + "\n")
        else:
            data_file.write(key + "=" + str(value[0]) + str(value[1]) + "\n")
    data_file.write("\n")
```